# Adding modifier .tabViewStyle(.page) breaks NavigationStack embedded in TabbedView

Tags: swiftui-tabview

This seems like a bug to me or I am just missing something obvious...as soon as I add the .tabViewStyle(.page) modifier to the below code it breaks the NavStack navigation. I can click the NavLink once and when I go back from the detail view I can't click on anything again. Here is the code:

```
struct TabbedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
                NavStack()
                .tag(1)
                NavStack()
                .tag(2)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page) //this BREAKS navigation
    }
}

struct NavStack: View {
    let arrs: [String] = ["First Group", "Second Group"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ForEach(arrs, id: \.self) {_ in
                NavigationLink("Link") {
                    Text("test")
                }
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        }
    }
}
```